# Group of order 27 acting on set with 135 elements

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

This is a past exam question (so no solutions are provided) and it asks to prove that if a group $G$ with $27$ elements acts on a set $X$ with $135$ elements then for every $x_i$, $x_j$ in $X$ the stabilizers coincide; $Stab(x_i)= Stab(x_j)$.

What I did was to write the class equation $$135=|X|=\sum_{x_i}|O(x_i)|$$
where the $x_i$s are orbit representatives ($ O(x_i)$ denotes the orbit of $x_i$). Then I substituted​ $|O(x_i)|$ with $|G|/|Stab(x_i)|$ and I am here
$$27\cdot 5=135= \sum_{x_i}\frac{|G|}{|Stab(x_i)|}$$
which in turn gives
$$5= \sum_{x_i}\frac{1}{|Stab(x_i)|}$$
but I don't really know what to do know. I've solved many exercises with actions that were rather trivial but this one seems to need something else... Thanks in advance!

Comment: As it stands, this is not true. You could have a mixture of orbits of lengths 1, 3, 9, and 27 adding up to 135, and that would give a mixture of stabilizers of orders 27, 9, 3, and 1, respectively. Perhaps you have missed out some information?

Comment: The truth is that it is not the original exam paper that I have but a forum post describing the questions... I will ask further. Thank you!